# Microphone Permssion in Pie not listing all apps

Tags: permissions, bugs, 9.0-pie

I have a Pixel phone. Recently I checked App permissions →Microphone permissions, and it shows 5 of 24 apps allowed.

But when I open the microphone permissions, it lists only 4 apps. Is this normal behaviour ?

[image]

Comment: Thanks for editing your question. I am deleting my answer because I can't help with the missing 3 dots. Maybe some Pixel owners can help

Comment: @androidbeginner Did you confirm with a 3rd party app like Addons Detector or aSpotCat?